# Calling a function from an other function in the same class without passing self

Tags: python, function, class, self

Let's say in my class, I have a callback function from a library (python-telegram-bot). Within that callback function I have to call another function in the same class. I can't modify the arguments in the definition of the callback and add 'self'. What is/are the proper ways to do call that second function without passing 'self'?

```
class MyClass():
    def other_function(arg):
        print (arg)

    def new_member(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        other_function(arg_value)

    new_member_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.new_chat_members, new_member)
    dispatcher.add_handler(new_member_handler)
```

Comment: your code doesn't demonstrate **library**

Comment: Why can't you modify the arguments of the callback? If it isn't going to be an instance method, **then don't out it in the class at all**. If it doesn't have access to the class state then it should just be a regular function in the module level.

Comment: Is declaring `other_function` as static method an option?

Comment: Your callback function does take a self arg, it just calls it `arg1`.  Your question might be more clear if you focused on what function you're calling in the *library*, and what you expect it to do.  Passing an instance method (and automatically binding `self`) as a callable that doesn't itself expect a `self` is a completely normal thing to do and is probably the thing you want to do here; I think you're complicating it needlessly.

Comment: Even if you don't make `other_function` a static method, accessing it via the class itself gives you the actual function, not a bound method. `MyClass.other_function(arg2)`. But really, your class isn't designed well and should be fixed or replaced.

Comment: @Samwise Whether or not `arg1` is bound to an instance of `MyClass` depends on how it is called, though.

Comment: When you're registering the callback, you can use `instance.callback_function` and the instance will be the `arg1` argument.

Comment: I modified the question and code to give more details. The library I use is python-telegram-bot. How to call other_function() from new_member()?

Comment: @chepner if inside new_member() I call MyClass.other_function(arg2), then I receive the error "name 'MyClass' is not defined"

Comment: Why are you using a class in the first place? Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with enough context to understand the problem properly.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I use a class because the project contains many classes. Without a class it is easy for me to call a function from another function but that's not what I can implement. The problem is to call a function in the same class without access to "self". I put a sample of the code to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

You should define the method with a `self` argument before the arguments that the library provides.

```
class MyClass():
    def callback_function(self, arg1, arg2):
        print(arg1)
        self.other_function(arg2)

    def other_function(self, arg2):
        print(arg2)
```

Then when you're registering the callback, use `instance.callback_function` (where `instance` is an instance of `MyClass` that you created) to provide a method that's bound to that instance.

Or if the method doesn't need to use `self`, you can declare with `@staticmethod`. Then use `MyClass.callback_function` when registering.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga should be fixed now.